# Pyinstaller and guidata

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am having problems with pyinstaller and guidata.

My script form.py is the basic example of http://pythonhosted.org/guidata/examples.html

Then I create the form.exe: python pyinstaller.py -F form.py

But when I run form.exe I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 386, in impo
rtHook
    mod = _self_doimport(nm, ctx, fqname)
  File "C:\Python27\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 480, in doim
port
    exec co in mod.__dict__
  File "C:\Users\usuario\Documents\test\build\
pyi.win32\form\out00-PYZ.pyz\guidata", line 540, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 386, in impo
rtHook
    mod = _self_doimport(nm, ctx, fqname)
  File "C:\Python27\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 480, in doim
port
    exec co in mod.__dict__
  File "C:\Users\usuario\Documents\test\build\
pyi.win32\form\out00-PYZ.pyz\guidata.config", line 19, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\usuario\Documents\test\build\
pyi.win32\form\out00-PYZ.pyz\guidata.configtools", line 100, in add_image_module
_path
  File "C:\Users\usuario\Documents\test\build\
pyi.win32\form\out00-PYZ.pyz\guidata.configtools", line 86, in add_image_path
WindowsError: [Error 123] El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sin
taxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos: u'C:\\Users\\usuario\\Documen
ts\\test\\dist\\form.exe?175104\\guidata\\images\\*.*'
```

Any help?